# How to find every third word from a string

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-function

I'm trying to create a function that accept string as an argument  like following is an example

`this is a sample string and i need to use uppercase letter for every third word in this string`

and how to get an output like below

```
position;word
-------------
3       ;"a"
6       ;"and"
9       ;"to"
12      ;"letter"
15      ;"third"
18      ;"this"
```

I know how to create a function but I couldnt find a way to find my desired output

```
create or replace function fn_every_third(str text) returns table(pos bigint,wrd text) as
$$
--code to get the output
$$
language sql
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace function fn_every_third(str text) returns table(pos bigint,wrd text) as
$$
with cte as(
select  * from(
select row_number() over() rn,word from(
select unnest(regexp_split_to_array(str,' ')) word)t)q
)
select rn ,word from cte 
where rn in (select generate_series(3,(select max(rn) from cte),3))
order by rn 
$$
language sql
```

Use:

```
select * 
from fn_every_third('this is a sample string and i need to use uppercase letter for every third word in this string')
```

---

Reference:

- [row_number() over()(*Window Functions*)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/tutorial-window.html)
- [regexp_split_to_array()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html#FORMAT)
- [generate_series()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-srf.html)
- [`WITH` Queries](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-with.html)
- [`unnest()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-array.html#FUNCTIONS-ARRAY)